# Crossfading scenes in Android using OpenGL

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, fade

I am making a game for android and I am using OpenGL for rendering.

I would like to know if it’s possible to make a crossfade effect so that I can use it when I switch between menus.

I thought of making each object in one of the scenes gradually more transparent so that the scene behind it will become visible. But the problem with this approach is that if I make one of the objects on a scene transparent, all the objects behind it on the same scene will be visible even though they might have not been visible once the object was opaque.

So I would like to know is it possible to render a whole scene, then render a new scene over the previous scene and assign transparency to the new scene.

Answer (score 1):

One option (and the one I would probably take) is to render both scenes to FBOs and then fade between the FBOs displayed as a full-screen quad. Think of it like taking a screenshot.

Take a look at [this example](http://blog.shayanjaved.com/2011/05/13/android-opengl-es-2-0-render-to-texture/) to see a simple way of doing it.